# Getting the name of a column as an additional argument to function in a mutate_all tidy pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to use a column's name inside a function, without explicitly giving it as an argument to that function, called in a tidy (`dplyr`, `tidyr`, `purrr`, ...) pipe. This is because I would want to use this function on many columns (e.g. with `mutate_all` and `map`), not `mutate`ing each column separately.

Example:

Let's say I'd like each value in each column to be prefixed by that column name and an underscore. The following works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

tib <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)

f <- function(value, column_name) {
  str_c(column_name, "_", value)
}

tib %>%
  mutate(a = map_chr(a, f, "a"),
         b = map_chr(b, f, "b"),
         c = map_chr(c, f, "c"))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     c
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1   a_1   b_4   c_7
2   a_2   b_5   c_8
3   a_3   b_6   c_9
```

But what if I have n >> 3 columns?

It would be nice to have a function which finds out the column name by itself, then I can use `mutate_all`:

```
f2 <- function(value) {
  column_name <- miraculously_get_column_name()
  str_c(column_name, "_", value)
}

tib %>%
  mutate_all(f2)
```

But that's no going to happen. A probably more realistic wish is to enter as an additional argument to `mutate_all` an expression which finds the column name to each column and use the original `f`, something like:

```
tib %>%
  mutate_all(f, get_column_name_somehow())
```

So how do I do this with a pipe (and if there's another way and no way of doing this with a tidy pipe, let's have it then).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
tib %>% map2_df(names(.),f)
```

Or as @aosmith mentions in the comments you can use `imap_dfc` which is the precise answer to your question:

```
tib %>% imap_dfc(f)
```

Comment: That's amazing, my only issue is that I don't get it. But that's on me, thanks. `map2_dfr`? What happend to `map2_df`?

Comment: yes `map_df` works too, it's in the package index but not mentioned in the doc, `map_df`, `map_dfr` and `map_dfc` give the same result here

Comment: The dot in `names(.)` calls the main input, `tib` in this case

Comment: data.frames are lists, so `map2_df` iterates through its elements (columns) and at the same time iterates through names, and execute `f` at each step on this set of 2 parameters

Comment: @GioraSimchoni The `_df` suffix is being replaced by `_dfr` to make it clearer that it's a row-bind. See the fourth bullet in the [NEWS here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/NEWS.md#map-functions)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Also see the new `imap_dfr`, which is shorthand for `map2_dfr(x, names(x),...)`

Comment: great, thanks @aosmith, I edited my answer. Can you give me an example where `map2_df` / `map2_dfr` / `map2_dfc` don't give the same result ? I'm confused

Comment: Theoretically `map_dfc` is for column binding, but I don't know of a scenario off the top of my head where it would work differently.  `map2_dfr` works the same as and will eventually fully replace `map2_df` (which will be deprecated).